# How do i find my wifi gateway ip when i have multiple virtual local network device?

Tags: c#, network-programming, uwp

My objective is to find my wifi ap gateway ip.

This is the code I use to find my gateway.

```
    private string GetIpv4Gateway()
    {
        // get local ip
        var localIp = Dns.GetHostEntryAsync((Dns.GetHostName()))
            .Result
            .AddressList
            .Where(x => x.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            .Select(x => x.ToString())
            .ToArray();

        IPAddress address;

        if (IPAddress.TryParse(localIp[0], out address))
        {
            //Valid IP, with address containing the IP
        }
        else
        {
            log.Error("Invalid IP");
        }

        // split the ip
        string ipTemp = localIp[0];
        string[] splitValues = ipTemp.Split('.');

        // replace the ip with gateway ip
        splitValues[3] = "1";

        //reconstruct the ip
        string ipGateway = "http://" + splitValues[0] + "." + splitValues[1] + "." + splitValues[2] + "." + splitValues[3] + "/";

        return ipGateway;
    }
```

Basically, what it does is get all local network ip segment (192.168.0.x, 169.254.185.x), make assumpsion that the first device is the wifi ap network segment and replace the last number of the ip to 1. It works when the first network device has ip like 192.168.0.x, but it failed when the first network device is 168.254.185.x (which is nmap virtual network device).

How do i know which network ip segment is my wifi ip segment?

Comment: You could use the MAC ID.  Ping the device and then check the ARP table from cmd.exe >ARP/a to find MAC ID.

Comment: What do you mean by MAC ID? Mac address? What if I dont know the gateway Mac Address? Im using UWP and UWP does not allow ICMP and ARP ping.